# FSM pattern detector in verilog

Tags: verilog, fsm

I am trying to make a finite state machine which detects a 12-bit pattern `110001010111`, but I can't get the tick where it is supposed to be.
I have added the code, testbench and the waveform I got.

Code:

```
module  seqdet  
(input  clk,rst,
 input wire in,
 output reg y); 
    parameter   w=4'b0000,a=4'b0001,b=4'b0010,c=4'b0011,d=4'b0100,e=4'b0101,f=4'b0110,g=4'b0111,
                h=4'b1000,i=4'b1001,j=4'b1010,k=4'b1011,l=4'b1100;  
   //wire  in=Q;
   //assign in=Q[17:6];*/
   
    reg [3:0]   nst,    st; 
    always  @   (posedge    clk)    
    begin
    if  (rst)   st  <= w;
    else    st  <= nst;
    end

always  @   *   
begin
    nst =st;
    y = 1'b0;
    case(st)
        w:  if(in)  nst =a;
        a:  if(in)
            nst =b;
            else    
            nst =w;
        b:  if(in)
            nst =b;             
            else    
            nst =c;
        c:  if(in)
            nst =a;             
            else    
            nst =d; 
        d:  if(in)
            nst =a;             
            else    
            nst =e; 
        e:  if(in)
            nst =f;             
            else    
            nst =w; 
        f: if(in)
            nst =b;             
            else    
            nst =g; 
        g:  if(in)
            nst =h;             
            else    
            nst =w; 
        h:  if(in)
            nst =b;             
            else    
            nst =i; 
        i:  if(in)
            nst =j;             
            else    
            nst =w; 
        j:if(in)
            nst =k;             
            else    
            nst =w; 
        k:  if(in)
            nst =l;             
            else    
            nst =c; 
        l: begin y=1'b1;
            if(in)
            nst =l;             
            else    
            nst =c; 
            end
        default:nst =w;
        endcase
    end
endmodule
```

TestBench:

```
`timescale 1ns / 1ns
module fsm_detector_tb();
    //declerations
    parameter T = 20; //clock period in nanoseconds
    reg clk, reset;
    reg test_input;
    wire test_tick;


    seqdet uut(
        .clk(clk),
        .rst(reset),
        .in(test_input),
        .y(test_tick)
        );

    // clock
    // 20 ns clock running forever
    always
    begin
        clk = 1'b1; //high
        #(T/2); // delay half a period
        clk = 1'b0; //low
        #(T/2); // delay half a period
    end

    initial
    begin
    //    reset = 1'b1;
    //    test_input = 1'b0;
    //    #(2*T); // delay two clock cycle

        reset = 1'b0;
        test_input = 1'b1;
        #(T); // delay one clock cycle
        test_input = 1'b1;
        #(T); // delay one clock cycle
        test_input = 1'b0;
        #(T); // delay one clock cycle
        test_input = 1'b0;
        #(T); // delay one clock cycle
        test_input = 1'b0;
        #(T); // delay one clock cycle
        test_input = 1'b1;
        #(T); // delay one clock cycle
        test_input = 1'b0;
        #(T); // delay one clock cycle
        test_input = 1'b1;
        #(T); // delay one clock cycle
        test_input = 1'b0;
        #(T); // delay one clock cycle
        test_input = 1'b1;
        #(T);
        test_input = 1'b1;
        #(T);
        test_input = 1'b1;
        #(T);
        $finish;

    end


endmodule
```

[image: This is the Waveform I get]

The output should be high where it is marked on the waveform, and I can't figure out where it went wrong.

Comment: `b:  if(in) nst = b; else nst = c;` - can you explain why you think this is correct?

Comment: Where's `st` in the simulation?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in the testbench.  The inputs are not properly synchronized to the clock.  You should drive the inputs  in the testbench the same way as you drive them inside the design code: use `@(posedge clk)` and nonblocking assignments (`<=`) instead of `#` delays and blocking assignments.  Replace your `initial` block with the following:

```
initial begin
    reset      = 1;
    test_input = 0;

    repeat (2) @(posedge clk); reset <= 0;

    @(posedge clk) test_input <= 1;
    @(posedge clk) test_input <= 1;
    @(posedge clk) test_input <= 0;
    @(posedge clk) test_input <= 0;
    @(posedge clk) test_input <= 0;
    @(posedge clk) test_input <= 1;
    @(posedge clk) test_input <= 0;
    @(posedge clk) test_input <= 1;
    @(posedge clk) test_input <= 0;
    @(posedge clk) test_input <= 1;
    @(posedge clk) test_input <= 1;
    @(posedge clk) test_input <= 1;

    repeat (3) @(posedge clk);
    $finish;
end
```

This guarantees the simulator will use behave as expected.  I see `test_tick` go high when you expect it.

[image: waves]

---

This code also asserts reset at time 0, then releases it a couple cycles later, which guarantees that your design will be reset properly.